# PHP $_POST vs saving data in an array

Tags: php, performance

This is not an bug or issue. But while I was reading about a lot of performance realated articles I came to know about how javascript variables take more resources to load and so it is better to put the global variable for javascript into a local variable to work - specially in for loops.

So I was wondering if such thing also happens on $_POST with PHP. 
As in will it give me a performance improvement if I have lot of post data. Save that in a local array say $post_data = $_POST;

And then I reference in where required.

Comment: I don't think there will be an appreciable performance improvement, if any.

Answer (score 2):

Not really worth the time.  `$_POST` is already an array in memory, so no need to duplicate it.

To get the size of `$_POST` in bytes, you can do this:

```
strlen(serialize($_POST));
```

(`serialize` will turn any object into a string which can be saved and `unserialize`d. )

---

FWIW in `for` loops, if you don't cache the length of the array and instead use something like this...

```
for(var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {}
```

...JS will have to recalculate `.length` each time it starts an iteration, so it's expensive, particularly over big arrays.

Comment: The second part of your answer seems unrelated to the question.

Comment: @Jack - yeah just threw in my two cents...OP mentioned JS for loops, got excited :)

Answer (score 0):

In php the main concern with globals is memory. Performance difference in accessing a global or local scoped variable is negligable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the JavaScript part (can you provide a reference, please?). In PHP this would effectively create a copy of $_POST array and hence would use more memory without having any effect on speed improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If you make:

```
$post_data = $_POST;
```

PHP will create just **reference** to info in `$_POST` variable, so you **will not have** more memory usage, till changind info in `$post_data`. If you try to change data when PHP will create copy of information in memory.